# Understanding Backbone extend

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, prototype, javascript-objects

I'm a big fan of Backbone, but recently have come across some bizarre behavior with Backbone's extend. I call it bizarre probably because of a combination of misunderstanding the intention, and not understanding the deep nitty gritty of how javascript works. **Long story short, modifying a property of any instance gets reset to the default when re-instantiating the object, modifying a sub property will change it for all future instances.** I would love any insight into the matter.

Here is some code using Backbone's extend:

```
var myObj = function () {
    this.a = true;
};

myObj.extend = extend; //the backbone version, link provided at bottom

//the pattern used throughout backbone
var myExtension = myObj.extend({
    b: "hello"
});

var instance1 = new myExtension();
instance1.b = "goodbye";

var instance2 = new myExtension();
console.log(instance2.b); //logs hello!!

var myBadExtension = myObj.extend({
    b: {
        c: "hello"
    }
});

var bad1 = new myBadExtension();
bad1.b.c = "goodbye";

var bad2 = new myBadExtension();
console.log(bad2.b.c); //!!! logs "goodbye" !?!?!?!
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

[Link to backbone extend](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1648-L1679).

Comment: In my case, it happens where there are arrays as attributes of a model. Setting one, set's it for all objects and then to solve I used `_.clone` before setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because `bad2.b` and `bad1.b` is the same object, coming from their shared prototype. To avoid this, you should assign `b` a value in the `initialize` method.

```
var myBadExtension = myObj.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      this.b = {
        c: "hello"
      };
    }
});
```

It won't matter if a property is primitive (IOW not an object or an array), but I think it's more common to initialize primitives in the same way.

Given you are not using backbone's built-in classes, this might have a better chance of working.

```
var myBadExtension = myObj.extend({
  constructor: function() {        
    myObj.apply(this, arguments);

    this.b = {
      c: "hello"
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Edit: Initialize is not magically called like it would be for a Backbone view. Is there some equivalent outside of this particular convention? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're a hero. Well done sir. I understand the patterns better now thanks.